# Counter-example for prime ideals in a non commutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

*Algebra*, by T. W. Hungerford, page 127. Theorem 2.15.
''If $P$ is an ideal in a ring $R$ such that $P \neq R$ and for all $a, b \in R$
\begin{equation} \label{1} 
ab \in P \Rightarrow a \in P \mbox{ or } b \in P, \hspace{2cm} (1)
\end{equation}
then, $P$ is prime. Conversely if $P$ is prime and $R$ is commutative, then $P$ satisfies condition $(1)$''
 **Remark:** Commutativity is necessary for the converse.

If I understood it correctly, there should exist a ring $R$ which is not commutative, with a prime ideal $P$ with the following property: $ab \in P$ and $a \notin P$ and $b \notin P$.

This is the example I had asked for in the previous version of my question.

PS: Definition of prime ideal, according to Hungerford:

''An ideal $P$ in a ring $R$ is said to be **prime** if $P \neq R$ and, for any ideals $A, B$ in $R$, $$AB \subset P \Rightarrow A \subset P \mbox{ or } B \subset P. $$

Comment: What do you mean by "if $P$ is prime and $R$ is commutative the condition holds". To me that condition IS the definition of prime ideal in a commutative ring. =S

Comment: I don't understand your question. That's the definition of a prime ideal. Isn't it?

Comment: Are you using the more general (and quite more complex) definition of prime ideal in a non-commutative ring? Which is the one you have?

Comment: I think you should write a proper ideal $P$ is a prime ideal in $R$, if for any two **ideals** $I,J$ in $R$, $IJ \subseteq P$ implies that $I \subseteq P$ or $J \subseteq P$. You have confused ideals with elements in the statement of your problem. Otherwise, your question makes no sense. And what theorem have you proved exactly? I'd like to know.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. I edited the question. Hope it's clearer this time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just look at the zero ideal of $M_2(F)$ for a field $F$.

It’s prime (because it’s maximal) but there are clearly zero divisors.

To distinguish the two concepts in noncommutative rings, we usually call an ideal satisfying the commutative definition of prime a “completely prime ideal.”